# PowerShell: How to find and uninstall a MS Office Update

Tags: powershell, ms-office, uninstallation

I've been hunting for a clean way to uninstall an MSOffice security update on a large number of workstations.  I've found some awkward solutions, but nothing as clean or general like using PowerShell and `get-wmiobject` with `Win32_QuickFixEngineering` and the `.Uninstall` method on the resulting object.

[Apparently, Win32_QuickFixEngineering only refers to Windows patches.  See: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverpowershell/thread/93cc0731-5a99-4698-b1d4-8476b3140aa3 ]

Question 1: Is there no way to use `get-wmiobject` to find MSOffice updates?  There are so many classes and namespaces, I have to wonder.

This particualar Office update (KB978382) can be found in the registry here (for Office Ultimate):

`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{91120000-002E-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}_ULTIMATER_{6DE3DABF-0203-426B-B330-7287D1003E86}`

which kindly shows the uninstall command of:

`msiexec /package {91120000-002E-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE} /uninstall {6DE3DABF-0203-426B-B330-7287D1003E86}`

and the last GUID seems constant between different versions of Office.

I've also found the update like this:
    `$wu = new-object -com "Microsoft.Update.Searcher"`
    `$wu.QueryHistory(0,$wu.GetTotalHistoryCount()) | where {$_.Title -match "KB978382"}`

I like this search because it doesn't require any poking around in the registry, but:

Question 2: If I've found it like this, what can I do with the found information to facilitate the Uninstall?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on your second approach (using Microsoft.Update.Searcher), this solution should allow you to search for an update by Title then uninstall it:

```
$TitlePattern = 'KB978382'

$Session = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session

$Collection = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl
$Installer = $Session.CreateUpdateInstaller()
$Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()

$Searcher.QueryHistory(0, $Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()) | 
    Where-Object { $_.Title -match $TitlePattern } |
    ForEach-Object {
        Write-Verbose "Found update history entry $($_.Title)"
        $SearchResult = $Searcher.Search("UpdateID='$($_.UpdateIdentity.UpdateID)' and RevisionNumber=$($_.UpdateIdentity.RevisionNumber)")
        Write-Verbose "Found $($SearchResult.Updates.Count) update entries"
        if ($SearchResult.Updates.Count -gt 0) {
            $Installer.Updates = $SearchResult.Updates
            $Installer.Uninstall()
            $Installer | Select-Object -Property ResultCode, RebootRequired, Exception
            # result codes: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc720442(WS.10).aspx
        }
    }
```

Comment: `CreateUpdateInstaller()` must be called from an elevated process.  Therefore, it can't be used via the likes of `invoke-command`.