# Uninstalling MS Office Update ( KB Article ) using Powershell/ Batch Command

Tags: powershell, batch-file, ms-word, patch

Is there a clean way to uninstall MS Word KB Article using Batch/ PowerShell command?

Background:

I've been trying to uninstall one KB Article (KB4475558) MS Word 2013. As a part of solution to manual team, who wants to uninstall all newly installed KB articles. I'm successful in trying to install multiple KB articles. But uninstalling has been quiet tricky.

So far tried,

Approach 1:
 `wusa /uninstall /KB:4475558`
 `wusa.exe /uninstall /kb:4475558 /norestart /quiet` 
---- It gives "This Action is Only Valid for Products That are Currently Installed" Error.

Approach 2 : Using GUID

`Msiexec /I {90150000-006E-0401-1000-0000000FF1CE} MSIPATCHREMOVE={80BC2A33-0ADF-4731-AC75-046BA9B6B7AF} /qb`
---- It gives "This Action is Only Valid for Products That are Currently Installed" Error.

Approach 3:

using Microsoft.Update.Searcher via link below,

[PowerShell: How to find and uninstall a MS Office Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762648/powershell-how-to-find-and-uninstall-a-ms-office-update)

-- Doesn't work.

Can you please help me on these questions:

1: I have manually installed those KB Articles, I'm able to uninstall it manually: But through scripts, it shows the above error. Why is it so?

2: Any other approach I might be missing?

Note :
MS Office is not installed only MS word and Share point and there is no Trail version available in my machine.
I also tried rebooting the machine once, but no avail.

Any help would be greatly helpful ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) to parse the uninstall string from the registry uninstall key? *I wouldn't usually recommend this method, but it may be better than nothing.*

```bat
@(For /F "Delims=" %%G In (
    '^""%__AppDir__%reg.exe" Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /S /F "(KB4475558)" /D 2^>NUL^|Find "{"^"'
)Do @For /F "Tokens=2*" %%H In ('^""%__AppDir__%reg.exe" Query "%%G" /V "UninstallString" 2^>NUL^"')Do @Echo(%%I)&Pause
```

If you're satisfied with the results, you could modify the code to try uninstalling it, *(it is likely that you'll need to run the script or command 'As administrator')*:

From a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```bat
@For /F "Delims=" %%G In (
    '^""%__AppDir__%reg.exe" Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /S /F "(KB4475558)" /D 2^>NUL^|Find "{"^"'
)Do @For /F "Tokens=2*" %%H In ('^""%__AppDir__%reg.exe" Query "%%G" /V "UninstallString" 2^>NUL^"')Do @%%I
```

or from [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd):

```dos
For /F "Delims=" %G In ('""%__AppDir__%reg.exe" Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /S /F "KB4475558" /D 2>NUL|Find "{""')Do @For /F "Tokens=2*" %H In ('""%__AppDir__%reg.exe" Query "%G" /V "UninstallString" 2>NUL"')Do @Echo(%I
```

---

If you were trying to do it for all KB updates for your office products, something like this may get you close:

```bat
@(For /F "Delims=" %%G In (
    '^""%__AppDir__%reg.exe" Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /S /F "0FF1CE}_Office" /K 2^>NUL^|Find "{"^"'
)Do @For /F "Tokens=2*" %%H In ('^""%__AppDir__%reg.exe" Query "%%G" /V "UninstallString" 2^>NUL^"')Do @Echo(%%I)&Pause
```

If you're satisfied with the results, you could modify the code to try uninstalling it, *(it is likely that you'll need to run the script or command 'As administrator')*:

From a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```bat
@(For /F "Delims=" %%G In (
    '^""%__AppDir__%reg.exe" Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /S /F "0FF1CE}_Office" /K 2^>NUL^|Find "{"^"'
)Do @For /F "Tokens=2*" %%H In ('^""%__AppDir__%reg.exe" Query "%%G" /V "UninstallString" 2^>NUL^"')Do @Echo(%%I)&Pause
```

or from [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd):

```dos
For /F "Delims=" %G In ('""%__AppDir__%reg.exe" Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /S /F "0FF1CE}_Office" /K 2>NUL|Find "{""')Do @For /F "Tokens=2*" %H In ('""%__AppDir__%reg.exe" Query "%G" /V "UninstallString" 2>NUL"')Do @%I
```

---

*Please note that the examples above are only parsing the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`. There may be other locations, such as `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` holding information your require too.*

Comment: Thanks! I'll try them and let you the results. Just wondering a bit about why you would not recommend it! I mean is there any issues or something associated with it?